# form submit after preventDefault not working until submit button is clicked a second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form where I validate some fields by means of jQuery and after checking that everything is correct I want to submit the form. So first I prevent the form to be submit when the submit button is clicked, I perform the validations and finally if everything is correct I submit the form. But my form is not submitted until the submit button is clicked twice. How can I solve it?

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ... // Validation actions
    if (form_ok) {
       $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/owjbbu06/2/ - should be just fine

Comment: Side note: it would be simpler to do `if( !form_ok ) { e.preventDefault(); }` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tfp07kum/8/)

**CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form1').submit(function(e) {
        var form_ok=$(":text").val().length>0;

        if(!form_ok)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```